# Merge results of 2 queries where joined column may be missing data in either table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the feeling this has a really simple solution and I'm just suffering a brain freeze, but I hope you can help.

I have 2 tables that have identical layouts but data from separate systems and I want to combine them in a query for reporting purposes. But the column I would normally join on may have values that are only in one or the other table.

**Table A**

```
Date       | Sales
-------------------
20/12/2010 | 500
19/12/2010 | 450
```

**Table B**

```
Date       | Sales
-------------------
20/12/2010 | 200
18/12/2010 | 70
```

I want these in a result set as so:

**Result**

```
Date       | Sales A | Sales B
-------------------------------
20/12/2010 | 500     |    200
19/12/2010 | 450     |    NULL
18/12/2010 | NULL    |    70
```

This look so simple and obvious but I can't get it right, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Using Outer Joins in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213228(v=sql.80).aspx):

> **Using Full Outer Joins**
>   To retain the nonmatching information by including nonmatching rows in the results of a join, use a full outer join. Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2000 provides the full outer join operator, `FULL OUTER JOIN`, which includes all rows from both tables, regardless of whether or not the other table has a matching value.

```
select
  coalesce(TableA.Date, TableB.Date) as Date,
  TableA.Sales as SalesA,
  TableB.Sales as SalesB
from
  TableA
  full join TableB on TableA.Date = TableB.Date
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `full outer join` to match queries from both tables.  Then `isnull` can pick the date from the left or right side:

```
select  IsNull(A.Date, B.Date) as Date
,       A.Sales as [Sales A]
,       A.Sales as [Sales B]
from    A
full outer join B
on      A.Date = B.Date
```

Interesting read: [Coding Horror post on SQL join types](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).